# Position div in between 2 other divs

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble positioning a div in between 2 other divs (a header and footer) and I was wondering what css statement would achieve this. I'm not too familiar with what the margins can do in relation to other div items, right now I'm using `position: absolute;` and it's doing what I want. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the natural layout for divs: http://jsfiddle.net/kMPBC/ Your use of position:absolute is breaking the normal document flow.

HTML

```
<div id="header"></div>

<div id="content"></div>

<div id="footer"></div>
```

CSS

```
#header {
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
}

#content {
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
}

#footer {
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Would this work the same if I used % for the height instead of px (i.e) 15% 75% and 10%

Comment: Yes, but they will need a parent container with an explicit height, otherwise 15% of what? See http://jsfiddle.net/kMPBC/3/

Comment: Well this is for mobile so I want the header to be 15% of the screen, the footer 10% and the middle 75% and scrollable if there is not enough room to fit the content while keeping the header and footer fixed

Comment: So you want the header/footer to grow dependant on the size of the content?

Comment: Not really, I guess I want the content to grow dependant on what's in the content. I want the size of the header and footer to stay the same (percentage wise) and the size of the content to stay the same size (with respect to the viewable screen) but add in a scroll bar if the contents can't fit in the 75%